# Fourier-series odd vs even square wave?

Tags: homework, fourier-series

I really need to know the difference when doing a fourier seires between even and odd square waves. I've been trying to understand but I just get the same results and the same spectrums... Is the difference in the formula? If so, I can't find any formulas online that match with that my professor gave me. They're all a little different.

[image: photo of work done, enhanced, rotated, trimmed]

Comment: If you show your calculations for both kinds of waves, it'll be easier to tell if/where you might be making a mistake.

Comment: Okay here, updated

Comment: when you just **shift** a signal in time (to make it even for example) the Fourier series coefficients **magnitude** spectrum will be the same but their **phase** spectrum will change.

Answer (score 2):

For a trigonometric Fourier series:

$$
\tilde{x}(t) = a_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(n \omega_0 t) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin(n \omega_0 t)
$$
with
$$
a_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}  x(t) \ dt
$$

$$
a_n = \frac{2}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}  x(t) \cos (n \omega_0 t) \ dt, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots
$$

$$
b_n = \frac{2}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}  x(t) \sin (n \omega_0 t) \ dt, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots
$$
and $ \omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{T} $ .

the Fourier series of an odd square wave will be a sum of only sine terms, and the Fourier series of an even square wave will be a sum of only cosine terms.

This is because the product of an odd and an even function is an odd function, which when integrated over a symmetric interval (i.e. from $-T/2$ to $T/2$), will return zero. For an odd square wave, this means that all the $a_n$ will be zero, and for an even square wave, all the $b_n$ will be zero.

You can save yourself time and potential mistakes by exploiting this fact and only computing the coefficients that are nonzero.